# Rebasing a Git branch step by step from the merge base up to the head

Tags: git, rebase

I have a Git repository with a main branch A and an old maintenance branch B:

```
A0 -> A1 -> A2 -> A3 -> ... -> An (main branch A)
       \
        \-> B1 -> B2 -> B3 -> ... -> Bm (branch B)
```

The main branch has diverged a lot from the branch B, while the branch B cherry picked some changes from A and got features missing from the branch A.

I'd like to rebase to branch B on top of the branch A, but git rebase simply reapplies the commits B1..m on top of the head of the branch A, which leads to many unsolvable conflicts.

Is there a way to rebase the branch B on the branch A but gradually, commit by commit from A1 to An, with a conflict resolution at each step? This would be equivalent to executing:

```
git checkout B
git rebase A1
git rebase A2
...
git rebase An
```

Comment: I thought git rebase reapplied all of the commits on top of the desired commit, and would stop to resolve conflicts after each commit (if necessary). Have you tried this?

Comment: @TrueWill It stops after each commit of the merged branch B, but it starts on the last commit of the branch A. In this specific case resolving the conflicts is too difficult.

Comment: Just run rebase in a loop. I would search for the earliest commit in branch A that is likely to produce conflicts, call it C, then rebase ahead right before that commit C^ (and so skip over some uncritical commits), and then rebase onto C. Then repeat with the next candidate for conflicts.

Comment: [git-imerge](https://github.com/mhagger/git-imerge)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it with several options.

### Rebase option

Just use `git rebase -i A B`
Rebase state starts as an interactive mode, you can change order of commits (just move rows up or down). You also can change `pick` on to `edit` and your rebasing will step-by-step for each `edit`.

Rebasing will be interrupted when conflicts will raise. This state calls `interrupted rebase`, you can use `git status` to find where is conflict.
Try to resolve conflict, save file, and append your changes in to index stage - `git add <filename>`.
When conflicts will be resolved, just `git rebase --continue` to continue your rebase history of B above history of A.

### Cherry-pick option

You can do this with `git cherry-pick [-n] <commit>` to reach same result like above with rebasing. But it's slowly and should be done manually.
`-n` option allows you to get all changes in index stage `git status`, edit those and continue with `git commit + git add`